# MICROSOFT ACCESS CREATING QUERIES WITH CALCULATED FIELDS

Tags: ms-access

Hey am working on access using if function is a little tricky in queries
here is my code `if(Stipend>200,total: [months]*[stipend])`

[image]

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in titles (or indeed in questions) - it's generally regarded as equivalent to shouting.

Comment: Try `IIF([stipend]>200,[months]*[stipend],0) AS Total`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Total: IIf([Stipend]>200,[months]*[Stipend],<someotherexpression>)
```

Replace `<someotherexpression>` with the expression to calculate and return if `Stipend` is less than 200.

Also, avoid using fancy names like *Student's Table* as table or field names.